# MySQL union/full outer join not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, union, full-outer-join

I have 2 tables one listing people and their relationships to their properties and a table of the list of properties (firstname, lastname etc).

Each person in the people table may not have all the properties listed in the properties table.  What I want is each person returned with a row for every property if they have a link to it or not.

So for instance

```
Properties              Person
prop_id|prop_name       person_id|prop_id|prop_value
-----------------       -----------------------------------
1      |firstname        10      | 1            | john
2      |lastname         11      | 1            | sean
                         11      | 2            | connery
```

The result I want is this

```
10 | firstname | john
10 | lastname  | null
11 | firstname | sean
11 | lastname  | connery
```

Note that john/10 has a last name row but is null.

I thought this query would give me the result but it does not give me the null row for john that I desire.

```
select person_id, prop_value, prop_name
from person
left outer join properties on person.prop_id = properties.prop_id
union
select person_id, prop_value, prop_name
from person
right outer join properties on person.prop_id = properties.prop_id
```

This query omits the 10 lastname null row.  Is this query possible?  This is MySQL/MariaDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to join the `person` table to the `properties` table twice to get this to work. Something like this maybe:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.person_id, p2.prop_value, prop.prop_name
FROM person p1
  CROSS JOIN properties prop
  LEFT JOIN person p2 ON p1.person_id = p2.person_id AND prop.prop_id = p2.prop_id
```

This is demonstrated working in @RomainBar's [sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dadb90/7](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dadb90/7)

Comment: It will work if you add a `DISTINCT` to @cf_en query : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dadb90/7
If you don't use 2 joins you can't have person_id not null and prop_value null as they are from the same table

Comment: Thanks for the note on distinct and the sqlfiddle. I've added the `DISTINCT` into the answer.